# TeamSpeak server on Android

Tags: android

Can I host a TeamSpeak server on my Android tablet? Is there any application that can do that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. This is not a programming question.

Comment: I think http://android.stackexchange.com/ is better suited for this types of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirements for the server are listed here: https://forum.teamspeak.com/threads/124175-What-are-the-minimal-System-Requirements?p=425377#post425377 or search in the web

1. They offer binaries, probably written in C++ (you can guess this if you look at the requirements for the Linux servers).
2. They mention Intel processors as a requirement.

So, since it's not Java (based on above guess), you can't hope to run it on the Android's JVM. And since it's not for ARM binaries (the processor architecture used by most all Android tablets), you can't hope to run it as a native binary.

In short: No, you can't.